# Navigating to an archive.org link in a comment loads malformed Retrocomputing URL

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, hyperlinks

[The comment in question](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/1613/main-board-of-the-original-game-watch-ball/1614#comment2588_1614)

Clicking the link to open it in my current window or a new tab creates a malformed URL:

```
https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/1613/http://main-board-of-the-original-game-watch-ball/http://iwataasks.nintendo.com/interview-club-nintendo.html#/game-and-watch-ball-reward/0/0
```

Copying the link using right click -> Copy Link Address, copies the correct link:

```
http://web.archive.org/http://iwataasks.nintendo.com/interview-club-nintendo.html#/game-and-watch-ball-reward/0/0
```

Comment: Cross-reported on [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/286411/242209).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), according to Marc Gravell on [Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/286487/242209):

> Thanks to @IlmariKaronen's excellent detective work, it looks like
>   refer[r]er plays a strong role here. The good news is that we've
>   already done the work to make markdown-mini emit `rel="nofollow noreferrer"` links (rather than just `rel="nofollow"`); this should
>   have the happy accident of fixing this issue. The bad news is that
>   there's something banjaxed in the packaging of that component, so
>   those changes didn't  get deployed cleanly. I'll get that straightened
>   out and deploy when I can.

This has been deployed as of two hours ago.